# How do I add a suffix to every value in one column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, directory, suffix

I keep trying to add a suffix to every single value in one column in a dataframe. I accidentally added what I wanted to be a suffix as a prefix. I don't know how to fix this. How do I change the prefix to a suffix in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

If your prefix is the same for every column and thus has a fixed length, you can trim that off using `df[column].str[prefix_length:]`. E.g. your prefix is '_asdf', so you want to trim off the first four characters from your column with `df[column].str[4:]`.

To add a suffix, you can use `df[column] = df[column] + suffix`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str` accessor to transform prefix as suffix.

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
           col1
0  _suffixHello
1  _suffixWorld
```

With [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace(r'(_suffix)(.*)', r'\2\1', regex=True)
print(df)

# Output
           col1
0  Hello_suffix
1  World_suffix
```

Or using [`str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html):

```
suffix = '_suffix'
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.slice(len(suffix)) + suffix
# same as
# df['col1'].str[len(suffix):] + suffix
print(df)

# Output
           col1
0  Hello_suffix
1  World_suffix
```

Comment: I tried  str.slice and I keep getting ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: `str.slice` and more generally the `str` accessor is ONLY available for `Series`. So you need to select ONE column from your `DataFrame` to perform string operations.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create a series to work with of 8 randomly chosen colors:

```
colors = np.array(['blue','brown', 'black', 'cyan', 'green', 'maroon', 'magenta', 'orange','pink', 'purple', 'red', 'teal','yellow' ])
```

s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(a = colors, size = 8, replace = False))

[image]

Assign a string that you'd like for your suffix to the variable, 'suffix':

Then use the apply method with a lambda function to concatenate your suffix to each element in the series. Make sure the dtypes of all your elements in your series/column are strings. If they're numbers, convert them to a str first, otherwise, you'll get an error because of mis-aligned dtypes.

[image]